# SQL TOTAL AND GRAND TOTAL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

hEY ALL

i have a table that shows transactions and their status. How can i create a column that shows the total of  transactions that are completed,rejected,declined and the grand total of all on a different column

for example i am looking something like this

```
Completed 100
Rejected 50
Declined 20
Total        170
```

In 3 different rows..

The table fields are something like this.

```
transaction_id
status_id,
date
transaction_number
```

Comment: Check out http://tinyurl.com/so-hints to get better at asking questions - here on SO or in general in any forum, on- or offline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the textual status you mention in your desired output corresponds to the `status_id` column in your table, you could use something like:

```
SELECT status_id, count(*)
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY status_id WITH ROLLUP
```

This works for SQL Server 2000 and newer - not sure if other RDBMS have the exact same syntax... (unfortunately, you didn't mention **what system** you're using...)

The `WITH ROLLUP` will cause an extra line to be added to your result with a `status_id` of NULL - this is the total of all counts combined.

You didn't mention how to "translate" the `status_id` into a textual description - that could be added if you provide the necessary info....

Comment: +1, you can add a COALESCE to include the word "total": `SELECT COALESCE(status_id,'Total'), count(*)...`

Comment: @KM: ALl I get with that approach is: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Total' to data type int."